# Binded Property is null on ajax call using Razor

Tags: razor, razor-pages

Let's say I have a binded textarea :

.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Header" rows="3> </textarea>
</div>
<button type="button" id="printTestButton" asp-page-handler="PrintPreview" class="btn btn-primary"> button </button>
```

i don't show you the ajax code.. since it's not the issue.

Code behing .cs :

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        this.Header = "Foo";
    }

    public ActionResult OnGetTest()
    {
        console.log(this.Header);

        return new JsonResult("Received " + header + " at " + DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

So when I call the webpage, the OnGet Function is called. I then set the Header property to be equal to "Foo". Magic happens, I can see on the UI that the textarea contains the string "Foo".

[image]

Now the problem : When I press the button and then I call with Ajax the function OnGetTest(), the property Header is null.

Why is Header null if I just set it to be equal to "Foo"? On the UI we can see "Foo". Why is the binding property doesn't work at this moment ?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript method to handle the click of printTestButton?  I think you will need to share that code, as it would seem that your AJAX call is not submitting the data.  If it was a button of type "submit", then the data would be automatically submitted to the server.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `BindProperty` attribute only supports binding of property values in `POST` requests. You have to opt in to support `GET` requests:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
public string Header { get; set; }
```

Ref: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-data-from-get-requests <sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> (*I own the Learn Razor Pages site*)

Comment: I tried But it didn't work. I still need to pass all the arguments via the Ajax data object to get access to the property.